# How can create a table that uses an aggregate of distinct values across multiple columns as a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create a table that takes the distinct combinations of 2 columns and only returns those that are greater than one.

What I have so far creates a table of all companies and contracts associated with them.

```
Company  Contract
-------  -------- 
ABC      0000111
ABC      0000113
DEF      0000124
GHI      0000207
GHI      0000389
GHI      0000567
```

It also creates a second table that finds distinct combinations of those columan and creates a list of how many times they appear.

```
Company  Countr
-------  -------- 
GHI      3
ABC      2
```

I am trying to make a third table that returns just those rows that have companies matched with more than one contract.

```
Company  Contract
-------  -------- 
ABC      0000111
ABC      0000113
GHI      0000207
GHI      0000389
GHI      0000567
```

Modified source, if it helps

```
SELECT DISTINCT inventory.company, inventory.contracts
FROM inventory
WHERE inventory.company not in ('Company Name')
( 
    SELECT
       DISTINCT inventory.company,
       count(DISTINCT(concat(inventory.company, inventory.contracts))) AS Countr
    FROM inventory
    WHERE
    inventory.company not in ('Company Name')
    GROUP BY company 
    HAVING count(DISTINCT(concat(inventory.company, inventory.contracts))) > 1 
)
ORDER BY Countr DESC
```

Comment: Hi Vyff.  Tagging MySQL and SQL Server together is considered bad form.  The two products work differently.  This means we need to know which you are using before we can help you.

Comment: My apologies. It is my first time posting, so I just used what stackoverflow recommended. I am using SQL server.

Comment: Vyff you have a couple of different answers here, to clarify can you confirm that you would want to see companies with multiple contracts even if they were the same?  For example would you want to return XYZ, 0000001 if there were two records in `inventory` both of which were XYZ, 0000001?

Comment: Eoins The database doesn't have those situations, we have another query to check that those dont happpen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE company in 
(SELECT company FROM inventory GROUP BY company HAVING count(distinct contract)>1);
```

The sub-query just creates a list of `company`s that have more than one `contract` associated with them.  Then selects all data `inventory` that matches those `company`s.  The `DISTINCT` modifier in the `Count` in the `HAVING` clause makes sure that there are multiple distinct contracts

[Here's a link to the functional schema and query](http://rextester.com/HPPG30970)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is necessary to create more than one table. Considering the information you gave I would do it as follows:

Create a table with company and contract information and call it `TABLE`

```
Company  Contract
-------  -------- 
ABC      0000111
ABC      0000113
DEF      0000124
GHI      0000207
GHI      0000389
GHI      0000567
```

Then I would create a view on that table as follows and call it `VIEW1`; the columns are called `COMPANY` and `CONTRACT_COUNT`, for example:

```
select company, count(contract) from TABLE group by company;
```

Then I would create another view, VIEW2, with different query:

```
select distinct TABLE.company, TABLE.contract from TABLE, VIEW1 where TABLE.COMPANY=VIEW1.COMPANY and CONTRACT_COUNT > 1
```